# I have .DDF files and .MKD files but i don't know how to connect it to pervasive sql

Tags: pervasive

I have .DDF files and .MKD files but i don't know how to connect it to pervasive sql.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to use the Pervasive Control Center (PCC) to add a new database.

Longer answer is to open the PCC, connect to the engine running the PSQL engine, right click and select "new database."  WHen the new database dialog is shown, set the Database Name and the location of the DDFs / MKD files and select OK.  Most of the other options are not required to be changed.
Full documentation on creating a Pervasive DB (for PSQL v12 but applies to versions as old as v9.5):
http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/javapcc.htm#158685